# angularjs internationalize dynamic label

Tags: angularjs, internationalization

I'd like to internationlize label fetched dynamicaly. I've tried something like this wihtout success:

```
<span class="nav-label">{{'{{menu.title}}' | translate}}</span>
```

Any idea?

```
function config($translateProvider) {

$translateProvider
    .translations('en', {         
        dashbord: 'Dashboard',
    })
    .translations('fr', {
        dashbord: 'Tableau de bord',            
    })
    ;

$translateProvider.preferredLanguage('en');
```

}

Comment: are you using [ng-translate](https://github.com/angular-translate/angular-translate)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You want to translate the key contained in `$scope.menu.title`, right? So use

```
{{ menu.title | translate }}
```

Comment: indeed key is contained in $scope.menu.title. But it's not working.. only key is rendered, not translation value!

Comment: That means that the key doesn't have any translation, or that the translations haven't been loaded yet. I'd guess that menu.title contain 'dashboard' instead of the incorrectly spelled 'dashbord' that is in your translations.

Comment: key does have translation. So how to ensure translations are loaded before rendering label?

Comment: What is the exact value of menu.title? Are you sure it's exatly equal to the key? Are there no leading or trailing spaces? Print the key, print its length, and tell what they are.

Comment: you were right JB, there's mispelling error on the key! Thanks a lot!