# What is the best approach for internationalization in Angular JS?

Tags: angularjs, internationalization

I am going to implement the internationalization in the existing angular 1.X project.

So what is the best approach to use/start with?

Any suggestions, please?

Thanks,
Gowtham

Comment: This is answered by the documentation https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/i18n

Comment: It wil help you http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30869693/angularjs-internationalize-dynamic-label?rq=1

Answer (score 0):

```
   var app = angular.module('at', ['pascalprecht.translate']);

   app.config(function($translateProvider) {
       $translateProvider.translations('en', {
           TITLE: 'Hello'
       });
       $translateProvider.translations('de', {
           TITLE: 'Hallo'
       });
       $translateProvider.preferredLanguage('en');
   });

   app.controller('Ctrl', function($scope, $translate) {
       $scope.changeLanguage = function(key) {
           $translate.use(key);
       };
   });
```

Please refer this for more info

```
https://angular-translate.github.io/
```

angular-translate is an AngularJS module that makes your life much easier